# Connection string in plain text and config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, web-config, connection-string

At the moment I have my connectionstrings in plain text in my code for development purposes.
Everything works lik a charm. However if I move my connection strings to a remote config file the following sql error appears :

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

I tried printing the connectionstring and it was identical to the one I had in plain text.

```
ConnString = "Initial Catalog=###;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=###;Password=###";
ConnFromFile = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString"];
Log.Message(ConnString ==ConnFromFile )
```

This resulted in True.

Comment: "to a remote config file"? on another machine? or just your local web.config? Who's running your app pool and does he have access to the DB? Might want to include a server=... part to your connection string

Comment: This is an asp.net question, not a Classic ASP one.  However if you were using Classic the best place for a connection string would be as an application variable in global.asa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=>Sql configuration manager,check tcp/IP, named pipeline is enabled,and VIA is disable